# Gorm mapping/self-reference for one-to-many relationship

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, one-to-many

So I have my domain below. Basically what I'm wanting to do is get all the demandNumbers for a given WorkOrderSummary. The data structure exists in the view already so I really just need to figure how I can map the WorkOrder-to-demandNumbers (one-to-many) relationship. So one lab_order_header_id can contain many demand_header_ids.

```
class WorkOrderSummary {

    String workOrderNumber
    Long demandNumbers
    String demandTypeName
    String statusName
    Date needByDate
    String customerName
    Long facilityId
    Long labDestinationId
    Long assetTagQuantity

    static hasMany = [demandNumbers: WorkOrderSummary]


    static mapping = {
        version false
        table name: 'work_orders_v', schema: 'lab'
        id column: 'lab_order_header_id'
        demandNumbers column: 'demand_header_id'
        demandTypeName column: 'demand_type'
        statusName column: 'status'
    }
}
```

Right now this is only getting me one-to-one in terms of lab_order_header_id to demand_header_ids.

Any suggestions?

Edit - 9/26/2016

Created another domain class for the demandNumbers and notated the belongsTo:

```
class SalesOrderSummary {

        String demandTypeName

        static belongsTo = [workOrder: WorkOrderSummary]

        static constraints = {
        }

        static mapping = {
            version false
            table name: 'work_orders_v', schema: 'lab'
            id column: 'demand_header_id'
            workOrder column: 'lab_order_header_id'
            demandTypeName column: 'demand_type'
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you have `demandNumbers` given as both type `Long` and as type `Set<WordOrdersSummary>` (from the `hasMany`).

Comment: It may be possible with a combination of `hasMany` and `belongsTo` to accomplish this without a join table/domain class, but I think this may be your best option - I've used this approach before (a join table) to link the self referencing objects.  If you use the join table, just remember to have `static mappedBy = [...]` in your WorkOrderSummary class.

Comment: @tylerwal Please see my edits from just now. I ended up creating a second domain class even though it's selecting from the same view. So it's essentially just joining to itself right?

Comment: The child `WordOrdersSummary` has to have a reference to the parent, by means of a column - in your view, what is this column? `demand_header_id` or is it `lab_order_header_id`? Without a join table, this is the only way to create the one-to-many relationship.

Comment: So in the view, the parent column is `lab_order_header_id` and the child is `demand_header_id`. So there can be many demand_header_ids to one lab_order_header_id. But I'm using demand_header_id as my id in SalesOrderSummary so I can join back to the WorkOrderSummary.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have many **DemandNumbers** for a given **WorkOrderSummary**
you should replace the following line:

```
static hasMany = [demandNumbers: WorkOrderSummary]
```

With the following line:

```
static hasMany = [demandNumbers: DemandNumbers]
```

It should make the relationship you are trying to get.

Comment: But I don't have a separate domain class called DemandNumbers. Won't that be an issue?

Comment: So you should create one if you wish to have that behavior. The current mapping is wrong.

Comment: But my DemandSummary domain class will look exactly the same as my SalesOrderSummary one.

Comment: Yeah, I understood it, but I am not sure that you have any other option. The Gorm probably does not understand the mapping you created at first, whereas it is a best practice to separate the code to 2 classes with different names.